# Logged out after running Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

Thanks for taking your time to read this.

Whenever I run a python script with any Tkinter command, I get instantly logged out of my user. I have been using Tkinter for weeks now and it was running just fine until yesterday when I clicked the demo button in the default menubar that shows up when launching a Tkinter GUI. It has been crashing now ever since if I include any Tkinter bits in the code. I have been using Python 3.7.7 with the Tkinter version that came with it before this problem started showing up. I have furiously tried everything I could think of including installing preceding and later versions from the official python.org page (3.8.2, 3.8.1, 3.8.0, 3.7.0, 3.6.6 etc.) or from brew. On some version of python, Tkinter runs and creates the main window with command tk.Tk(), however it would embed it into another window ([screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xH03o.png)). Weird stuff. I've searched across the internet for similar issues to no avail.

Operation System: MacOS Mohave 10.14.6

```
import tkinter as tk
tk.Tk()
# Then it either crashes on some python versions or acts weird and makes one window inside another
```

I hope I'm in the right place to seek help on this issue. I would be very thankful for any guidance.

Comment: Pick on from [`tkinter][macos] crash`](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=Is%3Aanswer+%5Btkinter%5D%5Bmacos%5D+crash)

Comment: @stovfl Thanks, I was able to find a workaround using the solution suggested by @ tcarroll2 from: https://github.com/pyenv/pyenv/issues/1375
The issue doesn't occur when using pyenv. It seems that the issue may have been caused by python sticking to the mac provided tkinter (version 8.5) instead of using a compatible version. With pyenv, I get python 3.7.4 and tkinter version 8.6.10 and it works flawlessly :)
Would be nice to be able to go back to my previous python 3.7.7 setup without facing problems, but this will work for now